# Adjusting the counter of \startitemize environment

Tags: enumerate, context, itemize, context-mkiv

I tried to find this answer on tex.stackexchange.com, the ConTeXt Garden wiki and the ConTeXt reference manual, and I feel like I must be overlooking something simple.

Basically, I have a list of items and I'd like to be able to manipulate the counter midway.

e.g.

```
\startitemize[n]
\item Item number 1
\item Item number 2
\magiccommand{8}
\item Item number 3
\stopitemize
```

Would produce:

```
1. Item number 1
2. Item number 2
8. Item number 3
```

Ideally any solution would work with nested lists also:

```
1. Item number 1
2. Item number 2
8. Item number 3
    8.1 Item number 3 (subitem 1)
    8.5 Item number 3 (subitem 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope someone corrects me if I'm wrong, but I can achieve the desired results using the following:

```
\def\updateitemcounter#1{%
    \setcounter[itemgroup:\currentparentitemgroup]
               [\currentitemlevel]
               [#1]%
}

\startitemize[n,joinedup,packed,repeat]
\item Item number 1
\item Item number 2
\updateitemcounter{7}
\item Item number 3
  \startitemize[n,joinedup,packed,repeat]
    \item Item number 3 (subitem 1)
    \updateitemcounter{4}
    \item Item number 3 (subitem 2)
  \stopitemize
\stopitemize
```

The above produces the following result (which in my case is desired [ignoring spacing]):

[image: List with updated counter]